# how to permanently change AWS RDS postgreSQL db timezone

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I need to permanently change my postgreSQL db timezone from AEST to UTC, the instance is on AWS rds.

On my AWS RDS postgreSQL parameter group, the timezone shows UTC but when i run
`show timezone;` it returns my local time zone which is AEST

the sql `SET TIMEZONE='UTC';` only change the session, so what's the right way to change the timezone to UTC permanently?

this link shows changing the parameter group value should work? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-change-time-zone/

thanks

Comment: In pg_settings view, what is the source given as?

Comment: run sql ```select name, setting, category from pg_catalog.pg_settings where name like '%timezone%'``` return values are:  name: timezone_abbreviations; setting: Default; category: Client Connection Defaults / Locale and Formatting;   thanks

Comment: You have the wrong column for the wrong row.  You need `select source, sourcefile, sourceline from pg_catalog.pg_settings where name = 'TimeZone'`, note the unusual case of the setting's name.

Comment: run the sql you told, the values are: source - 'client', sourcefile - NULL, sourceline - NULL.  not sure why there is no source file. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "source" of 'client' means that when your client connects, it sets the timezone it wants to use.  This will override anything you do globally and permanently on the database side, as the client can always change their own setting for this.

If you tell us what your client is and how it is configured, someone may be able to help you change this behavior.  For example if it is a libpq-based client, then having the PGTZ environment variable set will cause this behavior.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer, i will have a look at it tomorrow.